# ¿Hay manera de hacer este código más eficiente?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, revisión-de-código, eficiencia

Es un simple ejercicio que estoy realizando por mera práctica y ocio, lo he hecho de varias maneras pero me preguntaba si hay alguna manera incluso más práctica o de reducir las líneas de código haciendo uso de los muchos métodos de JavaScript.

El ejercicio se trata de recibir un array(arr) y un número(target) y devolver otro array con un par de números que se encuentren en 'arr' cuya suma sea igual a 'target'.

```
function targetSum3(arr, target) {
    let newArr = [];
    let copyArray = arr;
    for (let i of copyArray) {
        let x = Math.abs(i - target);
        copyArray.pop(copyArray[i]);
        if (copyArray.includes(x) && (copyArray.indexOf(x) != copyArray.indexOf(i))) {
            newArr.push(i);
            newArr.push(x);
            return newArr;
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Puedes ver múltiples soluciones a ese problema aquí https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Answer (score 0):

Estoy pensando, en recorrer el array que se pasa por parámetro y:

1. Construir un array sin el elemento que ocupa la posición de la iteración actual del array principal, utilizo [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para construir el nuevo array y [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para eliminar la posición i del array.
2. Sumar el elemento con todos los elementos del array construido sin él.
3. Si la suma es de los dos es igual a target, añadirlos al nuevo array y salir de los dos for apoyándome con la variable booleana fin.

```js
function targetSum3(arr, target){
  
  let i=0,j=0,elem;
  let vaux = [...arr];
  let newArr = [];
  let fin = false;
    
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if (!fin){
      elem = arr[i];
      vaux.splice(i,1);
      for (j=0;j<vaux.length;j++){
        if (elem + vaux[j] == target){
          newArr.push(elem);
          newArr.push(vaux[j]);
          fin = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
    vaux = [...arr];
  }
  return newArr;
}

arr = [7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10];
target = 14;
console.log(targetSum3(arr,target));
```

He modificado la respuesta, porque estaba utilizando la función filter para eliminar elemento en lugar de eliminarlo por posición, de esta forma en el array puede haber elementos repetidos.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre de la siguiente forma:

```js
function targetSum(arr, target) {
    const opts = {};
    for (const num of arr) {
        if (opts[target - num]) return [target - num, num];
        opts[num] = true;
    }
    return false;
}

const test1 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
console.log(targetSum(test1, 5));
const test2 = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(targetSum(test2, 6));
```

La complejidad de esta solucion es `O(n)`.

Solo necesitas llevar un registro de que pares de numeros completan el target, por eso la comparacion `target - num` y ya con eso tendrias la respuesta. Retornar `false` si no es posible encontrar un par de numeros que logren la respuesta.

---

Una alternativa para hacer esta solucion aun mas corta es no retornar nada en la ultima linea de la funcion, lo cual haria que si no se encuentran pares de numeros que cumplan con `target` el resultado seria `undefined`

```js
function targetSum(arr, target) {
    const opts = {};
    for (const num of arr) {
        if (opts[target - num]) return [target - num, num];
        opts[num] = true;
    }
}

const test1 = [1, 2, 2, 3]
console.log(targetSum(test1, 5));
const test2 = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(targetSum(test2, 6));
```